# Peer to peer communication dataset for research

Tags: data-request, research, language, text

I am looking for a peer-to-peer communication dataset, chat data, emails, phone calls, etc... any kind of conversation text between pairs of people for research. It would be much useful if the genders(or the names/nicknames) of both sides are labeled.

P.S. The language is not important. English, Spanish, French, German, Russian, Indian, etc... all welcome.